# Deleting a pointer in a map causes memory error

Tags: c++

I have three classes to represent database data. A `UserRow` a `HobbyRow` and a combined `UserAndHobbyRow` that has 1 `UserRow` but a map of X `HobbyRow`s. I get the UserRow, then I get the X HobbyRows and add it to the map in UserAndHobbyRow. I can print it out. But when I go to free the map data I get a memory error.

Please note that this is a small mockup to illustrate the problem. Suggesting to not use `new` here is not the answer because this is a simplified example. However what is identical is that everything is in the same function context.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

class UserRow {
    public:
        unsigned int id;
        std::string name;
        void Print();
        UserRow();
        ~UserRow();
};
UserRow::UserRow(){}
UserRow::~UserRow(){}
void UserRow::Print(){
    std::cout << " -- User Row -- " << std::endl;
    std::cout << this->id << std::endl;
    std::cout << this->name << std::endl;
}

class HobbyRow {
    public:
        unsigned int id;
        unsigned int userId;
        std::string hobby;
        void Print();
        HobbyRow();
        ~HobbyRow();
};
HobbyRow::HobbyRow(){}
HobbyRow::~HobbyRow(){}
void HobbyRow::Print(){
    std::cout << " -- Hobby Row -- " << std::endl;
    std::cout << this->id << std::endl;
    std::cout << this->userId << std::endl;
    std::cout << this->hobby << std::endl;
}

class UserAndHobbyRow {
    public: 
        UserRow *userRow;
        std::map<int, HobbyRow*> hobbyMap;
        void Print();
        UserAndHobbyRow();
        ~UserAndHobbyRow();
};
UserAndHobbyRow::UserAndHobbyRow(){}
UserAndHobbyRow::~UserAndHobbyRow(){}
void UserAndHobbyRow::Print(){
    std::cout << " -- User And Hobby Row -- " << std::endl;
    this->userRow->Print();
    std::map<int, HobbyRow*>::iterator it;
    for(it = this->hobbyMap.begin(); it != this->hobbyMap.end(); it++){
        it->second->Print();
    }
}

int main()
{   
    UserRow userRow;
    userRow.name = "My Name";
    userRow.id = 0;

    HobbyRow *hobbyRow = new HobbyRow[2];
    hobbyRow[0].id = 0;
    hobbyRow[0].userId = 0;
    hobbyRow[0].hobby = "sports";

    hobbyRow[1].id = 1;
    hobbyRow[1].userId = 0;
    hobbyRow[1].hobby = "cooking";

    UserAndHobbyRow userAndHobbyRow;
    userAndHobbyRow.userRow = &userRow;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        userAndHobbyRow.hobbyMap.insert(std::make_pair(hobbyRow[i].id, &hobbyRow[i]));
    }

    userAndHobbyRow.Print();

    std::map<int, HobbyRow*>::iterator it;
    for(it = userAndHobbyRow.hobbyMap.begin(); it != userAndHobbyRow.hobbyMap.end(); it++){
        delete it->second; // memory free error
    }

    return 0;
}
```

https://onlinegdb.com/Sy-KX20Ff

Comment: You need to delete the whole array, not its individual elements. But you shouldn't be using raw `new` in this case anyway.

Comment: Did you `new` something? If you didn't `new` something, you shouldn't delete it. They're a matched pair, like `malloc` and `free`.

Comment: Hint: you created the array with one statement `new HobbyRow[2]`. You need to delete the _array_ with one statement as well. Trying to delete each entry individually doesn't make sense, because they weren't `new`'d individually.

Comment: Why don't I have the address of each individual block where each `HobbyRow` was created? If I can operate on it (use `Print`) why can I not free it?

Comment: You can `delete` what you `new`d. You didn't `new` each individual HobbyRow object, you `new`d an array of two HobbyRow objects. You need to `delete [] hobbyRow` as a single operation.

Comment: Handy analogy: you buy a multipack of Xs from a shop, and each individual X is market "not for resale individually". If you want to return them for a refund, you need to refund the whole multipack. They're not going to give you an individual refund for each X, because that's not what you bought.

Comment: Interesting. I thought maybe doing new[] was just a convenient way of assigning x amount of memory blocks in a row and that they were otherwise unrelated. I understand if that was the case arrays wouldn't work at all !

Comment: What's going on behind the scenes is really interesting. Say you ask for an object that is 8 bytes long. You get 8 bytes, but you probably also get some book-keeping to help the system manage that 8 bytes, so now you could be up to 16 bytes. Next, to keep the memory manager simple, you could be given a generically sized block. You could ask for 8 and actually get 64 because that's the smallest block available. This leads to a lot of folk wondering how they could run off the end of their allocation without the program crashing or having some other visible error.

Comment: simple rule: `delete` what you `new`, `delete[]` what you `new[]`, `free()` what you `malloc()` and try as much as possible to write *none of those* yourself. Instead use `std::unique_ptr` and `std::vector`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use new to allocate memory for hobbyRow

```
HobbyRow *hobbyRow = new HobbyRow[2];
```

and you need to delete whole array

```
delete[] hobbyRow;
```

Currently you do the following:

```
delete &hobbyRow[0];
delete &hobbyRow[1];
```